# How to retrieve data from mongodb using localhost address and path to location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

How to retrieve data from mongodb using localhost address and path to location.

When i type 'localhost:8080/api/Deed/' in browser, i can see all data stored in mongodb collection in browser. Using same url how can i get data and save it in an array in json format in nodejs ?

Comment: You can use Mongoose npm package for NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a client to do so. There are a few like [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) where you can define a model for the data in your collections. If you don't want to model your data, you can always use a simple MongoDB client through the [mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) package. Either of these solutions will let you query however you like which you can then take the response of those queries and use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to save JSON json file